# Eclipse launcher shortcut in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: eclipse, .desktop, ubuntu-dock

I successfully installed Eclipse oxygen and created a launcher `Eclipse.desktop` file by reading some tutorials.

Whenever I launch Eclipse from this launcher, it successfully launches. But I want it in the dock or favourites for ease. When I try drag and drop, it just doesn't work. After launching Eclipse there is no Keep in favourites option too.

How to solve this.

Comment: That method doesn't work. Tried it. When I type the appropriate command and press Enter, nothing happens. Drag and drop, too, not working.

Comment: Did you place the `.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications/` first?

Comment: @pomsky, add your solution as an answer.

Comment: @crafter You can't add answers to closed questions! :) Also no need here, this question is marked as a duplicate of a correct target(s).